# Changing The Name On A Hard Drive That Comes From A SAN

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, rename, san

**Terms:**

- VM = Virtual Machine
- LUN = Logical Unit Number Used In SANs
- SAN = Storage Area Network
- S2K8R2 = Windows Server 2008 R2 OS

**Backstory:**

OK so I have a SAN (Dell MD3200) that I have created a bunch of LUNS on.  One LUN of 2TB was reserved for the FTP server.  So after creating the LUN called "FTP" I hopped over to my physical box (S2K8R2) and made sure the drive was showing in the disk manager (it was), then I added the disk to my cluster.  Once added to the cluster I moved that drive resource to my FTP VM.  The drive popped up in the FTP VM (S2K8R2) and I was using it like toast uses butter (I know, I won't do it again).

**Question:**

Now that I have the drive and using it on my VM I tried to change the name of the drive like all my other drives that are available to me (some also from the SAN).  But I can not change the name of my FTP drive to "FTP"!  I have tried doing it through the properties box and right clicking on it then rename.  I also tried using "label F:FTP" at the command prompt.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE:**

I was trying to also go the extent of trying to get the properties of the drive via diskpart.  So I needed to know the disk number (ex: Disk 5).  In doing this I noticed that in disk manager it shows up right...  Also, when doing diskpart my Disk 5 free space is totally wrong!  It says I have 1024KB free when it should reflect around 1020 (or so) GB because as you can see on the right it has (0.99TB) free.  Weird.
[image]

Comment: @Dave Really?...  That was meant to show I have already tried researching and make people smile....   All straight faces here.  :P

Comment: :) - The rules are not mine! :)

Comment: Well I guess in the end I did what I set out to do.  I got 2 smiles out of you!  haha